# Is it possible to visit some WWW page with a JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is to possible to give JS/PHP a link address to some page and make it to visit it or do something with it?
I want to download a content of a page, which address I pass into a form input.
So i would create a form and enter there a page address, like Google.com

```
<label>Enter address of a page you want me to visit</label><input type="text" id="pageAddress">
```

And after JS/PHP got there, it would run such function in that sites console:

```
(function(){
    document.location = 
        'data:text/attachment;base64,' +              
            utf8_to_b64(document.documentElement.innerHTML); //To Download Entire Html Source
})();

function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
  return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}
```

So whole script could visit page i want and download it's content. Is it possible?

Comment: `<?php $content = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'); echo $content;` Like this?

Comment: @SlackBadger has the way to download a page in PHP. You will need to be careful with this. This will not download images and such. If in the html the image is not a link to an actual website source, it will give an error since the path given does not exist on your website. Also note: since its a string you get returned from `file_get_contents()` you have to put it in a DOM element to look for a tag. You could also use regex to find a tag in the string. You do no have to put it in a DOM element than.

Comment: @wouter140 - it's ok. I just want to download some page's table. https://cenapaliw.pl/?o=&m=95&l=3&k=144 That page uses GET, so i could give a certain address to a form, and then have this page downloaded. I already have function which gives me only table from this page. But i want to be able to choose which subpage i want to download as data (from table at this site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.assign("url here");` in javascript.

Comment: Thank You, now i only have to execute my function (to download data i want to) with a callback(), when given page is loaded?